# How do I solve for the non linear homogenous PDE of this question

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$(D_{x} ^ 2 + 3D_{x}*D_{y} + 2D_{y} ^ 2) z = x + y$

I have been trying to solve this question by many methods but to no avail.

Comment: Hint: $a^2+3ab+2b^2 = (a+b)(a+2b)$

Comment: $(D_x * D_y)z$ is ambiguous. Clarify please.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this second-order non-homogeneous partial differential equation is linear; indeed, no non-linear expression of the function $z(x,y)$ or its derivatives are involved.

As Ninad Munshi pointed out in the comments, the differential operator in front of $z$ can be factored into $(\partial_x+\partial_y)(\partial_x+2\partial_y)$, since $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$ commute. In consequence, the *homogeneous* problem divides itself into the following sub-equations :
$$
\begin{cases}
   (\partial_x+\partial_y)z \;\,= 0 \\
   (\partial_x+2\partial_y)z = 0
\end{cases}
$$
The first equation gives $z = F(x-y)$, when the second one leads to $z = G(2x-y)$, where $F$ and $G$ are arbitrary functions, hence the homogeneous solution $z_H(x,y) = F(x-y)+G(2x-y)$.

One particular solution can be guessed to be $z_P(x,y) = \frac{1}{6}(x^3 + \frac{1}{2}y^3)$; nonetheless, if you wish to be more systematic, given that the source term is a first-degree polynomial with a second-order differential operator, the particular solution can be taken as a (bivariate) cubic polynomial in general.

The final answer is thus $z(x,y) = z_H(x,y)+z_P(x,y) = F(x-y)+G(2x-y)+\frac{1}{6}(x^3 + \frac{1}{2}y^3)$, where the arbitrary functions $F,G$ are to be determined thanks the boundary conditions.